# do I need classification method for my android gesture recognition app?

Tags: android, machine-learning

I'm developing an android application which recognizing accelerometer gesture. For now I'm just utilizing dynamic time warping to get the smallest distance between input gesture and about 200 unique gesture data in database. My application looping through the data and compare the input gesture with gesture data in the database one by one. It can find the smallest distance and recognizing the gesture for average in 5 second. The problem is can i speed up recognition time maybe for half second or less? Do I have to use classfication method like KNN and combine it with dtw method? an example or references will be apreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are currently doing is a 1NN. In other words, you are already running a simplest possible KNN method. with K=1. Changing K won't speed up anything, it can **only** change the quality of the result. To speed up the process you can think about using two approaches:

- Using some indexing methods, which will reduce the computational complexity of your distance based search. This problem is called Nearest Neighbout Search (NNS), and even [wikipedia provides quite a lot of information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) regarding its speed ups;
- Using completely different classification method, which build a much simplier model (possibly SVM or even some decision tree - it depends on your actual data).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. will look for it.

Answer (score 0):

My intuition is that Locally Sensitive Hashing can be quite easily applicable. For instance you could design them by picking K points randomly and checking if the time series isn't too "far" away.

I would go into more details on that idea, but instead I found this paper : http://dtai.cs.kuleuven.be/events/MLSA13/papers/mlsa13_submission_13.pdf , and it seems to be using much simpler LHS function.

So this is one way out, hope it works out. You can also implement an easy classifier and accept its answer if it is very certain about the gesture (I would recommend SVM here as in the answer above), and if it is close to the boundary decision look for the closest neighbour.

Answer (score 0):

you can do DTW at 10,000 hz, even on a phone, see this vid

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_qLzMMuVQg

eamonn

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong. This one is for subsequence matching.. but mine is for full sequence matching..